# How can I set up IIS to run server code for an HTML form?

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, server-side

If I have a simple html page with a small form whose data I'd like to store in a DB on the server, what do I need on my server to be able to accept the form input?

I'd rather not use any ASP.NET code in the HTML page.

Comment: Well, if you are using WebForms, you're going to have to have C#/VB code in either the code-front or the code-behind of the page.  If you don't want to put it there, where *do* you want it to go?

Comment: I am developing a client side application, but I do need some slight server side processing, so I am trying to find a quick way to incorporate some server side code. I am already familiar with aspx and have IIS built into my Windows machine, so I'm trying to levearage that.

Comment: If by "client side application" you mean either a fat-client winforms app, or a phone application, then you should be using web services: REST, SOAP, or otherwise.

Comment: @Kirk Woll I am trying to emulate a Java servlet with ASPX, it is largely a learning exercise; I'm extremely new to web application programming. I am unsure of what a fat-client winforms app is.

Comment: If you are literally trying to emulate a Java servlet, you may want to consider implementing an `IHttpHandler` instead.  That is the closest analog to a Java servlet in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Kirk Woll Thanks, this is what I'm looking for. If you post that as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the closest thing to a Java Servlet in ASP.NET is a raw implementation of `IHttpHandler`.  You'll note it has the following contract:

```
bool IsReusable { get; };
void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context);
```

This is very similar to a Java servlet which exposes the method:

```
service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res);
```

The difference being that in `ProcessRequest` you'll grab `context.Request` and `context.Response`.

Finally, you need to [register your handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx) in the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="/Url/Path/To/Your/Handler" type="SampleHandler, SampleHandlerAssembly" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML form submits data to the server. You will need *something* on the server that accepts this data and writes it to your database. This could be an ASP.NET app, PHP, Perl or Python scripts, or just about anything else that you can get to run on your server.

Your HTML page doesn't necessarily have to have any ASP.NET code, even if your server-side application is built with it.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I am hoping. I am assuming I need just an .aspx page sitting on my server which I can call with `<form name="input" action="html_form_action.aspx" method="get">` that has a `Page_Load()`   function. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Your ASPX page just needs to read the submitted fields and write them to the DB. Semantically, your request should be a POST, not a GET because it isn't idempotent.